# Cómo resolver la excepción "The request method matched multiple endpoints"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo una API bastante simple que al pegarle a uno de los endpoints me arroja el siguiente stack trace

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The
>   request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
>
> VimTube.Controllers.CategoryController.GetAllCategories (VimTube)
>   VimTube.Controllers.CategoryController.GetCategoryByName (VimTube)

Entiendo que esta fallando porque tengo dos metodos que apuntan a la misma URL. Los mismos son los siguientes

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Category>>> GetAllCategories()
{
    return _repository.FindAll();
}

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategoryByName([FromQuery]string name)
{
    return _repository.ListCategoriesWhichStartsWith(name);
}
```

Y mi clase controlador tiene el prefijo ***vimtube/categories***.

Mi idea seria tener estas url's

1. ***vimtube/categories*** devuelve listado de todas las categorias.
2. ***vimtube/categories?name=Ent*** devuelve las categorias que comienzan con el query que le paso.

Lei que con [FromQuery] esto era posible, pero al parecer no es asi. 
Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías especificar rutas para cada método que creas mediante `[Route("ruta")]`, lo que te quedaría algo así

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ruta1")]
public Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Category>>> GetAllCategories()
{
    return _repository.FindAll();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("ruta2")]
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategoryByName([FromQuery]string name)
{
    return _repository.ListCategoriesWhichStartsWith(name);
}
```

Ahora si quieres incluir parámetros en la Uri lo puedes hacer así `[Route("ruta1/{param1:int}")]` donde se ve claramente que le puedes específicar el tipo de dato, aunque yo sólo los he utilizado con `string` e `int`.

Y lo último, no recuerdo haber utilizado **[FromQuery]** para los parámetros, yo me limitaba a **[[FromBody]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)** y **[[FromUri]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)**

Nos comentas como te va :)

Comment: Pense en lo de tener rutas distintas pero mi idea era mantener la misma. Con respecto a FromUri. No esta disponible en .NET Core 3. 
Aun asi si ninguna respuesta soluciona mi pregunta, la suya es la mas cercana y acertada, por lo que la dare como aceptada.

Comment: En ese caso puedes tener la misma como base y en la que requieres parámetros pasados por query especificarlos solamente. De esa manera te queda la misma base (categories) pero una que recibe parámetros y otra no.

Comment: Es lo que intente, pero se que ve aun asi cuando una url tiene query parameters y es igual que otra sin query parameters, .NET Core no diferencia ambas. Por lo que a la segunda simplemente le puse [Route("search/{category}")]. Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the sentence [FromUri],for example:

```
[HttpGet]
public Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Category>>> GetAllCategories()
{
    return _repository.FindAll();
}

[Route("{name}")]
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategoryByName([FromUri]string name)
{
    return _repository.ListCategoriesWhichStartsWith(name);
}
```

Comment: Estas en SO en español, tu pregunta debe estar en expañol. Además debes dar detalles, explicar comó funciona el código para que el OP tenga claro lo que le estás mostrando. [edit] tu respuesta.